# Sass @at-root with "&" interpolation

Tags: sass

I want to change a CSS property if my selector is contained by an anchor tag.

now I have

```
.btn-crazy-class-name-that-i-dont-want-to-repeat {
   line-height:30px;
}
```

And I want to change the line height if the parent is an "a" link

```
.btn-crazy-class-name-that-i-dont-want-to-repeat {
  line-height: 30px;
  @at-root a & {
    line-height:40px;
  }
}
```

I want the result to be

```
a.btn-crazy-class-name-that-i-dont-want-to-repeat {
  line-height: 40px;
}
```

but right now I get `a .btn-crazy-class-name-that-i-dont-want-to-repeat` with the space.

SassMeister gist here: http://sassmeister.com/gist/a5b97c6d78cb4ed456cd